# Wired connection drops after a few seconds

Tags: networking, arch-linux, ethernet

When I connect to my wired network using `netctl`, the connection drops automatically after a few seconds. It happens both with DHCP and static configuration, but the wifi connection on the same network works perfectly.

What really bothers me is that there is absolutely nothing in the logs, the output of `journalctl` is absolutely normal during network start-up, and nothing happens when the network disconnects.

```
Aug 22 18:34:37 dimension polkitd[5127]: Registered Authentication Agent for unix-process:7050:2995548 (system bus name :1.66 [/usr/bin/pkttyagent --notify-fd 5 --fallback], object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.UTF-8)
Aug 22 18:34:37 dimension systemd[1]: Starting Networking for netctl profile static...
Aug 22 18:34:37 dimension network[7055]: Starting network profile 'static'...
Aug 22 18:34:37 dimension kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp4s0: link is not ready
Aug 22 18:34:37 dimension kernel: alx 0000:04:00.0 enp4s0: NIC Up: 1 Gbps Full
Aug 22 18:34:37 dimension kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp4s0: link becomes ready
Aug 22 18:34:37 dimension avahi-daemon[558]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface enp4s0.IPv4 with address 192.168.0.43.
Aug 22 18:34:37 dimension avahi-daemon[558]: New relevant interface enp4s0.IPv4 for mDNS.
Aug 22 18:34:37 dimension avahi-daemon[558]: Registering new address record for 192.168.0.43 on enp4s0.IPv4.
Aug 22 18:34:37 dimension avahi-daemon[558]: Registering new address record for 192.168.0.175 on enp4s0.IPv4.
Aug 22 18:34:37 dimension network[7055]: Started network profile 'static'
Aug 22 18:34:37 dimension systemd[1]: Started Networking for netctl profile static.
Aug 22 18:34:37 dimension polkitd[5127]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-process:7050:2995548 (system bus name :1.66, object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.UTF-8) (disconnected from bus)
```

I have tried connecting directly to the router, I have changed the IP addresses, and I have tried with `wicd` instead of `netctl`, with always the same issue.

I'm using an up-to-date Arch Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those still looking for an answer, I asked about the same issue on the Arch Linux forums and I got a (temporary) fix of the bug:
https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=201459